# Google Map visibly resizing on load

Tags: google-maps

I'm showing a Google Map within a div using the code below. When the page loads the map appears to bounce around before settling. Is there a way to stop this behavior? The page is [here](http://bahcalculator.org/nano/).

```
function initialize() {

    myform.search.focus();

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);

    var mapOptions = {

       zoom: 2,

       center: latlng,

       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

}
```

Comment: I don't see that behavior in Chrome on Windows.  What OS/Browser do you see it in?  What size/resolution monitor?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Chrome (28.0.1500.95) on a MAC OS (10.8.4). It's a very quick resize so maybe you are using faster internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

initially set the visibility-style of `#map_canvas` to `hidden`

Then wait for the `tilesloaded`-event to show the map(with a short delay):

```
google.maps.event
 .addListenerOnce(map,
                  'tilesloaded',
                   function(){var that=this;
                              setTimeout(function(){
                                  that.getDiv().style.visibility='visible'},
                                  100);
                   });
```

Comment: I tried this but couldn't get it working. Do I add this within the initialize function? I don't understand how the tilesloaded function is referring to the map_canvas to unhide it.

Comment: add it within initialize, at the end of the function. `this` refers in a listener added to `map` to the `google.maps.Map`-instance itself, the method `getDiv()` returns the HTML-element that contains the map(#map_canvas in this case)

Comment: Thanks that did the trick! What I did wrong was use $("#map_canvas").hide(); to change the visibility, when I needed to change it in the style sheet for this solution.